# TNS:protocol adapter error and no oracle service present

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to login into my Oracle database as `sys` user through `sqlPlus` but I keep getting `ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error`. One of the reason of this error is that oracle service not running however when I check services there is no `OracleService` there, there are only following services related to oracle and they all are already running.

`Oracle - OraDb11g_home1TNSListener` , `Oracle - OraDb11g_home1clrAgent` and `Oracle MTS Recover service`

Please help resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Database Configuration Assistant" and create an Oracle instance. This looks like a Windows installation of Oracle, so the assistant should be `%ORACLE_HOME%\bin\dbca.bat`.